# F#: Implementation of interface that returns reference to iterator

Tags: f#

I am implementing the Microsoft.VisualC.StlClr IVector and one of the member functions returns a reference to an iterator, like so

```
abstract begin :  
  :ContainerRandomAccessIterator<'TValue> byref -> unit
```

Would someone know how this interface function could be implemented?

B.

Answer (score 2):

after looking at this interface in Reflector I'd rather say that it is impossible to implement it in F#. Method *begin* (as well as some other methods) has custom required modifier [IsUdtReturn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.isudtreturn%28VS.80%29.aspx) (**modreq[IsUdtReturn]**) and it seems it is not recognized by F# compiler. However I'll be glad to know that I'm wrong.

Comment: +1, I was just looking at the method in Reflector and planning to write something along these lines. I'm also not sure if this can be somehow used from F#....

Comment: Here is the interface I'm implementing:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338044.aspx

Comment: so are you saying that I should stop trying and use some other container?

Comment: @user: I would recommend that. Are you trying to implement the interface because of some interoperability with C++ code?

Comment: yes.  I have a managed C++ library where I have exposed a function which takes a generic_container as argument.  I have managed STL types in the assembly.  I guess I can do some conversion in the C++ library.